# Custom Filter List View on cases using Visualforce and Apex?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

**'Sales Rep'** is one of the Role in my org. I want to create a custom view in which I can see **'only'** cases assigned to 'Sales Rep' role strictly using Salesforce visualforce and Controller. How to check **'Cases Assigned to specifice Role'** using SOQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Owner.UserRole.Name` as a filter, as in:

```
SELECT ... FROM Case WHERE Owner.UserRole.Name = 'Sales Rep'
```

Comment: Yes it worked. 
**select CaseNumber,OwnerId from case where Owner.UserRole.Name = 'Sales Rep'**